# Matrix Multiplication: Multiply each row of matrix by another 2D matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

I am trying to remove the loop from this matrix multiplication (and learn more about optimizing code in general), and I think I need some form of `np.broadcasting` or `np.einsum`, but after reading up on them, I'm still not sure how to use them for my problem.

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
         [11,12,13,14,15]])
#A is a 3x5 matrix, such that the shape of A is (3, 5) (and A[0] is (5,))

B = np.array([[1,0,0],
         [0,2,0],
         [0,0,3]])
#B is a 3x3 (diagonal) matrix, with a shape of (3, 3)

C = np.zeros(5)
for i in range(5):
    C[i] = np.linalg.multi_dot([A[:,i].T, B, A[:,i]])

#Each row of matrix math is [1x3]*[3x3]*[3x1] to become a scaler value in each row
#C becomes a [5x1] matrix with a shape of (5,)
```

I know I can't just do `np.multidot` by itself, because that results in a (5,5) array.

I also found this: [Multiply matrix by each row of another matrix in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538324/multiply-matrix-by-each-row-of-another-matrix-in-numpy), but I can't tell if it's actually the same problem as mine.

Comment: Yes, C is my desired output, but I would like to get it without needing the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [601]: C
Out[601]: array([436., 534., 644., 766., 900.])
```

This is a natural for `einsum`.  I use `i` as you do, to denote the index that carries through to the result.  `j` and `k` are indices that are used in the sum of products.

```
In [602]: np.einsum('ji,jk,ki->i',A,B,A)
Out[602]: array([436, 534, 644, 766, 900])
```

It probably can also be done with `mutmul`, though it may require adding a dimension and latter squeezing.

`dot` approaches that use `diag` do a lot more work than necessary.  The `diag` throws out a lot of values.

To use `matmul` we have to make the `i` dimension the first of 3d arrays.  That's the 'passive' one carries over to the result:

```
In [603]: A.T[:,None,:]@B@A.T[:,:,None]
Out[603]: 
array([[[436]],     # (5,1,1) result

       [[534]],

       [[644]],

       [[766]],

       [[900]]])
In [604]: (A.T[:,None,:]@B@A.T[:,:,None]).squeeze()
Out[604]: array([436, 534, 644, 766, 900])
```

Or index the extra dimensions away: `(A.T[:,None,:]@B@A.T[:,:,None])[:,0,0]`

Comment: Argument-less `squeeze()` is dangerous, and will do the wrong thing if other dimensions in `A` and `B` are 1. It looks like you want `.squeeze(axis=(1,2))` here.

Comment: As a note `np.einsum('ji,jk,ki->i', A, B, A, optimize=True)` will automatically handle the matmul calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain to calls to `dot` together, then get the diagonal:

```
# your original output:
# >>> C
# array([436., 534., 644., 766., 900.])

>>> np.diag(np.dot(np.dot(A.T,B), A))
array([436, 534, 644, 766, 900])
```

Or equivalently, use your original `multi_dot` train of thought, but take the diagonal of the resulting 5x5 array. This may have some performance boosts (according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html))

```
>>> np.diag(np.linalg.multi_dot([A.T, B, A]))
array([436, 534, 644, 766, 900])
```

Comment: Taking the diagonal means you're throwing away computations though, so this is less efficient than other approaches

Answer (score 0):

atTo add to the answers. If you want to make multiply the matrices you can make use of broadcasting. Edit: Note this is element wise multiplication, **not** dot products. For that you can use the dot methods.

```
 B [...,None] * A
```

Gives:

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [12, 14, 16, 18, 20],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [33, 36, 39, 42, 45]]])
```